# run-time error '13': type mismatch VBA 2010 to ensure uppercase text in cell

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

What's wrong with my code, every time I delete something on the worksheet it gives me a run-time error `'13': type mismatch`,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Address <> "$G$13:$J$13" Then
         If Target = Range("G13") Then
              test = UCase(Target.Value)
              If test <> Target.Value Then EnsureUppercase Target
         End If
     End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line is the error ?

Comment: You need to include the code for `EnsureUppercase`

Comment: The error code was on line
     If Target = Range("G13") Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `Error handling` and `Application.EnableEvents` when working with `Worksheet_Change` event

If the code provided converts the Range("G13") to Upper Case here is more simplified code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("G13")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
          Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @AdrianPaulGornall Please accept the asnwer if my post solved your problem.

Comment: Works perfect and i needed to translate the code to another 3 cells so i just did this.Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("G13, H13, I13, J13")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
          Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: @AdrianPaulGornall   Change this `Set rng = Range("G13")` to `Set rng = Range("G13:J13")`